# How do I print from Electron app directly to a particular printer?

Tags: node.js, printing, desktop-application, electron

I am using the following code in my render process and its working fine.

```
function printDocument() {
     window.print();
}
```

But  I would like to print directly to a particular printer to be set programetically. I also want to set the paper size manually.

I also want a list of available printers in the system.

Are there any printing API in electron or node that I can use?

I would like something like printDocument in c#

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that isn't a API for Electron to make that, just the normal options like silenct print or background. Maybe there's a node module with that functions, but i didn't found any